# Phonegap + Blackberry: no ondeviceready

Tags: cordova, blackberry

Developing PhoneGap + Blackberry has been my recent nightmare... the onDeviceReady is not firing and I can't find webworkers.js anywhere... 
Anyone has some kind of complex application running with BB 7.1?

**Adding the code:**
I'm using the default code in the PhoneGap sample:

```
<html>
<head>      
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webworks.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

And using ripple extension I'm getting the following console Log:

```
Viewport target-densitydpi is not supported. index.html:24
GET http:// localhost/bb/js/webworks.js 404 (Not Found) index.html:36
Ripple :: Environment Warming Up (Tea. Earl Gray. Hot.) ripple.js:475
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/bb/config.xml". ripple.js:484
webworks.handset :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.) ripple.js:475
eula response:  true ripple.js:483
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/bb/config.xml". ripple.js:484
Viewport target-densitydpi is not supported. index.html:24
GET http:// localhost/bb/js/webworks.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm using Windows 8 x64, could have something to do with it???

There is no Ripple folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5

Comment: Post some code otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: But do you know where webworkers.js is?

Comment: First of all, if you mean Web Workers as JS API, doesn't exist a file called webworkers.js. They're a native API. If you mean something different, you need to be more specific.

Comment: Yes I was talking about that file... :( this blackberry is very weired... Thank you

Comment: Nop, installed in Windows XP and the demo from PhoneGap still not working.... The ondeviceready never being raised in Ripple.

Comment: I don't see an handler attached on the ondeviceready event, moreover if you're testing your app in a desktop browser, the event will never be triggered. In a browser there isn't any ondeviceready event.

Comment: The webworks.js file is really only for the blackberry 10. You don't need to include it for bb7 and below or playbook. If you must need it, download the bb10 webworks sdk and use the command line tools to build the project. ie, ant qnx build. This will take the webworks.js file from your webworks sdk and place it in the www/js/ directory.

Comment: I can't manage to get the deviceReady working, so I just went with $(document).ready(function(){}) But this way I'm not very comfortable... :(

Comment: Aurelio, the event is attached in the app.initialize(). Shouldn't Ripple emulate this deviceReady behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem.   Remotely hosted code does not work as there is no webworks.js that I can copy to the remote web tree.

The sample code from phonegap doesn't work if hosted remotely.